# When may the dynamic type of a referred to object change?

Tags: c++, standards, virtual

Let us begin with an example:

```
#include <cstdio>

struct Base { virtual ~Base() {} virtual void foo() = 0; };
struct P: Base { virtual void foo() override { std::printf("Hello, World!"); } };
struct N: Base { virtual void foo() override {} };

void magic(Base& b);
// Example implementation that changes the dynamic type
// {
//     void* s = dynamic_cast<void*>(&b);
//     b.~B();
//     new (s) N();
// }

int main() {
    std::aligned_storage<sizeof(P), alignof(P)> storage;
    void* s = static_cast<void*>(storage);

    new (s) P();

    Base& b = *static_cast<Base*>(s);

    magic(b);

    b.foo();
 }
```

What, according to the Standard, should `b.foo()` print ?

*Personal opinion: it's undefined because `b` got stale after we destroyed the instance in `magic`. In this case, would replacing `b.foo()` by `static_cast<B*>(s)->foo()` make it legal ?*

---

So now that we have an example that may (or not) be legal, the more general question at hand for all of us standardistas is whether changing the dynamic type of an object is ever allowed. We already know that the C++ compiler may reuse storage (fortunately), so it's a bit tricky.

The question might seem theoretical, however it has immediate application for compilers: may the compiler devirtualize `b.foo()` to `b.P::foo()` in the program above ?

And therefore I am looking for:

- a definite answer regarding my own little program (I could not come up with one).
- a possible example (a single would suffice) of a legal way of changing the dynamic type of an object.

Comment: You're passing the address of the `void*` to placement `new`, are you sure that's what you meant to do?

Comment: As for the question, I do know that a reference cannot be rebound to a different object, which is what this is doing. So it seems to be undefined?

Comment: @BЈовић I assume `storage` is mistyped as `s` in `static_cast<void*>(s)`.

Comment: @SethCarnegie: Thanks for both typos. As for being undefined... I think so too, but I'd like to get a definitive answer.

Answer (score 3):

According to §8.5.3.2 of the standard, a reference cannot be bound to another object after initialisation. Since placement `new` creates a new object, you are violating that rule, and get undefined behaviour.

The dynamic type of an object cannot change. Even in your example, you're not changing the type of an object, but creating a new different object in the same place as the old one. If you think about it, changing the dynamic type of an object would imply *resizing the object in-place* to accommodate extra data members and changing the VMT (and then that would move other objects and screw up pointers...) which can't be done within the rules of the language.

Comment: This sounds promising. I have been looking up on explicit destructor calls and there is no special rule mentioned as far as I can see. Still looking through...

Comment: As @spraff pointed out, actually this is in contradiction with §3.8/7: *[...] a pointer that
pointed to the original object, a reference that referred to the original object, or the name of the original
object will automatically refer to the new object [...]*. You gotta love Standardese debates... (on the other 3.8./7 guarantees that the dynamic type did not change)

Answer (score 0):

It's [undefined behaviour](http://blog.llvm.org/2011/05/what-every-c-programmer-should-know.html). Your `magic` example is violating the semantics of a reference.

Also, `dynamic_cast` is for *down*-casting. Cast to `void*` is a `static_cast`.

To answer your questions explicitly:

- A compiler may "devirtualize" any function call it likes, if it can prove the runtime type.
- If a reference outlives the object it refers, it's UB.
- You cannot change the dynamic type of an object, the closest thing you can do is re-assign a pointer.

  ```
  Base * ptr;
  P p;
  N n;

  ptr = &p; ptr -> foo ();
  ptr = &n; ptr -> foo ();
  ```

But `p` and `n` are of fixed type until they go out of scope (or, if allocated on the heap, when they are `delete`d).

Comment: *If a reference outlives the object it refers to, it's UB* -> I think so too, but could not get my hand on a justification from **the Standard**, I was wondering if `b.~B()` would get a specific pass-through, notably. I know it sounds insane to ask for such a guarantee, but... the Standard does allow strange things.

Comment: Regarding the usage of `dynamic_cast`: this is a special construct of `dynamic_cast`, it has the effect of getting the address of the *full object*, no matter how complicated it is (even through virtual inheritance).

Comment: @MatthieuM. see my question regarding [similar considerations](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7586848/placement-new-breaks-consts-and-references)

Comment: @spraff: Ah! the paragraph you quote (3.8/7) seems exactly what I was looking for. It does not seem to leave much wiggle room! It could be worth citing it in your answer.