# Qt5: compile error while QSharedPointer<const T>::create()

Tags: qt, shared-ptr

Is it "expected" for QSharedPointer::create() not to work or is it a bug? I get an error:

```
/usr/include/qt5/QtCore/qsharedpointer_impl.h:439:9: error: 
invalid conversion from ‘const void*’ to ‘void*’ [-fpermissive]
new (result.data()) T(std::forward<Args>(arguments)...);
```

casting from nonconst shared pointer and constructor from raw const pointer work.

I got this for Qt5.7.0 and Qt5.10.0.

Here is a minimal example:

```cpp
#include <QSharedPointer>

struct A {};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    auto ca = QSharedPointer<const A>::create();
    return 0;
}
```

Here is one file (not minimal) example but with few working cases, 2 not working and a debug. Commented defines are for "not compiling" parts.

```cpp
#include <QSharedPointer>
#include <QDebug>

#define FROM_PTR
//#define CONST_CREATE
#define FROM_RAW_PTR
#define PERFECT_FORWARD_CREATE
//#define PERFECT_FORWARD_CREATE_CONST
#define BUILTIN_CAST


class A
{
public:
    A() = default;
    A(int i) : _i{i} {}
    void foo() const { qDebug() << "const foo" << _i; }
    void foo() {  qDebug() << "foo" << ++_i; }

private:
    int _i{0};

};

using ASPtr = QSharedPointer<A>;
using ASCPtr = QSharedPointer<const A>;


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Q_UNUSED(argc)
    Q_UNUSED(argv)

#ifdef FROM_PTR
    qDebug() << "FROM_PTR";
    auto a1 = ASPtr::create();
    a1->foo();

    auto ca1 = static_cast<ASCPtr>(a1);
    ca1->foo();
    qDebug() << "\n";
#endif // FROM_PTR


#ifdef CONST_CREATE
    qDebug() << "CONST_CREATE";
    auto ca2 = ASCPtr::create();
    ca2->foo();
    qDebug() << "\n";
#endif // CONST_CREATE


#ifdef FROM_RAW_PTR
    qDebug() << "FROM_RAW_PTR";
    auto ca3 = ASCPtr(new const A);
    ca3->foo();
    qDebug() << "\n";
#endif // FROM_RAW_PTR


#ifdef PERFECT_FORWARD_CREATE
    qDebug() << "PERFECT_FORWARD_CREATE";
    auto a2 = ASPtr::create(10);
    a2->foo();
    qDebug() << "\n";
#endif //  PERFECT_FORWARD_CREATE


#ifdef PERFECT_FORWARD_CREATE_CONST
    qDebug() << "PERFECT_FORWARD_CREATE_CONST";
    auto ca4 = ASCPtr::create(20);
    ca4->foo();
    qDebug() << "\n";
#endif //  PERFECT_FORWARD_CREATE


#ifdef BUILTIN_CAST
    qDebug() << "BUILTIN_CAST";
    QSharedPointer<A> a3 = ASPtr::create();
    a3->foo();

    auto ca4 = a3.constCast<const A>();
    ca4->foo();
    qDebug() << "\n";
#endif // BUILTIN_CAST


    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is a known Qt bug ([QTBUG-49748](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-49748?jql=text%20~%20%22qsharedpointer%20const%22)). Although it is marked as resolved in Qt 5.6.0, the bug is still present as pointed out in the comments.

## Why is this happening?

Look at the implmentation of the class QSharedPointer [qsharedpointer_impl.h](http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/src/corelib/tools/qsharedpointer_impl.h).

In particular the line:

```
new (result.data()) T(std::forward<Args>(arguments)...);
```

uses the result.data() as the new expression **placement params**. Unfortunately, one can **not** use a const pointer as a placement param (have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7586848/placement-new-breaks-consts-and-references) question here on SO for more details).

Hence, there's not much you can do except reporting this to Qt developers via the official bug tracker.

You may have a look at the smart pointers provided by the standard library (e.g. *std::shared_ptr*) if you are not forced to use Qt ones.

## **UPDATE**

As reported in Qt bug tracker, this bug was **fixed** in version **5.11** ([here](https://codereview.qt-project.org/#/c/229675/) is the related commit). Basically, they used **std::remove_cv** to remove the topmost const from the type specified.

Comment: Thanks. I created new [issue](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-68300).

Comment: I'll use `QSharedPointer<const T>(new T(...))`. It won't probably do anything with memory segmentation though.