# pthread does not seem to use updated global data value

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, pthreads

I am new to threads. I want to make two threads `xthread` prints 'X'; and `ythread` prints 'Z'; continuously until the user inserts `'C'` or `'c'` at `stdin`. I have made use of select to check if there is any userinput. If there is a userinput I use `scanf` to obtain it in `read` and do the comparison.

I have kept `read` as global. [Is there any other way of sharing non-global data between threads? ] . I have assumed that, when the user enters `'c'` at stdin the thread which is currently running reads it and stores it in `read and breaks out`. I have used the flag `read_input` to indicate to other threads that input has already been taken and you don't need to take userinput again.

**Problem**:

user enters `'c'`

xthread exits [or ythread]

However, ythread still keeps looping and exits only after i enter `'c'` again.
[My assumption is it has read the previous value of `read` and is still using the same value for comparing]

What have I done wrong?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<sys/select.h>
#include<pthread.h>
static unsigned int i =0;
char read;
int read_input = 0;

void* print_fn(void* arg)
{
    int fd = fileno(stdin);
    struct timeval tv = {0,0};
    fd_set fdset;
    int s;
    char *buffer = NULL;
    unsigned int len;

    while(1)
    {
        struct timespec t = {0,433300000};
        const struct timespec * tp = &t;
        nanosleep(tp,&t);

        printf("\nValue of read is %d",read);

        //sleep(1); 
        FD_ZERO(&fdset);
        FD_SET(fd, &fdset);
        printf("\n%p prints %c and i is %d",pthread_self(),*((char*)arg),i++);  
        if((s = select(fd+1, &fdset, NULL, NULL, &tv)) == 1)
        {
            printf("\nValue of s is %d",s);
            if(!read_input)
                scanf("%c",&read);
            fflush(stdin);
            printf("\nValue of read is %d",read);
            printf("\nChecked for %d or % d",'C','c');
            if(read == 'C' || read == 'c')
            {
                read_input = 1;
                break;
            }
        }
        printf("\nHere");
    }
    printf("\nI, %p survived while(1)",pthread_self());
    return NULL;
}

int main()
{

pthread_t xthread,ythread,checkThread;  
char c1 = 'X', c2 = 'Z';
pthread_create(&xthread,NULL,print_fn,&c1);
pthread_create(&ythread,NULL,print_fn,&c2);
pthread_join(xthread,NULL);
pthread_join(ythread,NULL);

return 0;
}
```

If there is a better way of taking userinput,please let me know.
I don't know if using `pthread_cond_t` would solve my issue. I don't find the necessity to use a mutex. [Correct me if I am wrong]

Comment: `read` is not `volatile`, so the thread may assume it doesn't change from outside. (Rather, the compiler assumes, and makes the thread read `read` only once.)

Comment: I shall add "Race Conditions" to the array currently containing `[ "Undefined Behavior", "SQL Injection" ]`, of which the members should always be written in bold and blue.

Comment: @Daniel Fischer I made read as `char volatile  read;` but the situation still persists.

Comment: @SuvP: You should be using a mutex for this purpose (i.e. to make read/write atomic). Refer to `pthread_mutex_lock` and `pthread_mutex_unlock`. If you are feeling adventurous, this may be done better still with a condition variable (`pthread_cond_t`) which also requires a mutex (this will signal the waiting thread to continue rather than checking a flag). A mutex is a fancy name for a semaphore of value 1. A semaphore is a fancy name for a lock which allows a specified number of users into the critical section.

Comment: @DanielFischer: I doubt `volatile` would help. You might like to read here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6858294/694576. What is missing here is a mutex, as *RageD* mentions, to protect `read` and `read_input` against concurrent access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apart from the other problems(as pointed by other StackOverflow-ers) in the code I posted.
I realized, the main issue was the line `/*3--->*/ if((s = select(fd+1, &fdset, NULL, NULL, &tv)) == 1)`. According to my logic, If one thread reads the char `c` from the user it sets `read_input` to 1. And, other thread when it accesses `read_input` reads the updated value (since its a global) and exits the while loop.

Now, since i was doing the check `/*2--->*/ if(!read_input)` within the `if` block of `/*3--->*/ if((s = select(fd+1, &fdset, NULL, NULL, &tv)) == 1)` something of this sort happens,

- User inputs `c`
- xThread reads `c` and sets `read_input` as 1
- yThread can't use the updated value of `read_input` until I enter
  something on the    console[even hitting the enter key would do]
  again. [That indicates    to `select` that some input is available]
  and we enter the    `if(select...block`  and can test `read_input`

Keeping rest of the stuff as it is,

shifting line `//1---->` to  `/*2--->*/` and the required `else` `/*4--->*/` does the trick.

```
/*2--->*/   if(!read_input)
        {
/*3--->*/   if((s = select(fd+1, &fdset, NULL, NULL, &tv)) == 1)
            {
            printf("\nValue of s is %d",s);
//1---->        if(!read_input) 
                printf("\nValue of read is %d",read);
                printf("\nChecked for %d or % d",'C','c');
                if(read == 'C' || read == 'c')
                {
                    read_input = 1;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
/*4--->*/   else
            break;
        printf("\nHere");
    }
    printf("\nI, %p survived while(1)",pthread_self());
}
```

**Note:** `volatile` was not needed

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any other way of sharing non-global data between threads?

Yes, it's called IPC (inter-proccess communication)
And it's possible to use it with pthreads.
This includes: Sockets, Pipes, shared memory, etc.

Regarding the Program itself, asDaniel Fischer wrote in the comment, read_input is not volatile, so the compiler is free to optimize it.

Comment: Even simpler, if he allocates a struct on the stack (assuming the stack persists throughout thread execution) or on the heap (this is simpler/safer), then he can simply pass that struct with the collection of variables to both threads as input data.

Comment: I agree, but this is a bit dangerous.

Answer (score 1):

The possibility of the compiler optimising away reads of `read` (bad name, by the way, if one wants to `#include <unistd.h>`) due to it not being `volatile` aside,

```
if((s = select(fd+1, &fdset, NULL, NULL, &tv)) == 1)
{
    printf("\nValue of s is %d",s);
    if(!read_input)
        scanf("%c",&read);
    fflush(stdin);
    printf("\nValue of read is %d",read);
    printf("\nChecked for %d or % d",'C','c');
    if(read == 'C' || read == 'c')
    {
        read_input = 1;
        break;
    }
}
```

you have the test that breaks the `while(1)` loop inside the `if(select(...))`.

So after the first thread read a `'C'` or `'c'` and exited, the other thread only ever checks the condition when new input is available from `stdin` (which on my system requires the <kbd>Return</kbd> key to be pressed).

Move that condition outside the `if (select(...))` for the second thread to have a chance to exit without `select` reporting that more input is available.

Also,

```
fflush(stdin);
```

is undefined behaviour. Although several implementations promise that it does something sensible, you should not rely on it.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense. It helped :) Enclosed the `if(select` in `if(!read_input){ ...//if(select   } else break;`

Answer (score 0):

The main problem of your code is that `read` is not `volatile` as Daniel said. This means the compiler does not know that it can be changed by an unforeseeable outside force like another thread.

Aside from that your code has a lot of errors and bad practices:

- Do not define symbols that have standard lib name equivalents like `read`.
- Don't use `select` on the same file descriptors in multiple threads. This is a recipe for disaster. If both threads return from the select simultaneously they will both attempt to read from `stdin` and only one will succeed, the other will block. If you want to use a file descriptor for synchronisation set it  to nonblocking and use `read`, it's not signal safe, but better then a full-scale race condition.
- always include `pthread.h` first.
- You are aware that you are incrementing `i` non-atomically (race-condition)? I didn't change that, but `__sync_fetch_and_add` would do the trick atomically.

This is a way:

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>

static unsigned int i =0;
volatile char char_read; // has to be volatile since you are checking it with both threads
volatile int read_input = 0; // has to be volatile

void* print_fn(void* arg)
{
    // int fd = fileno(stdin);
    int fd = 0; // stdin is always 0

    while(1)
    {
        struct timespec t = {0,433300000};
        const struct timespec * tp = &t;
        nanosleep(tp,&t);

        printf("\nValue of read is %d",char_read);

        printf("\n%p prints %c and i is %d",pthread_self(),*((char*)arg),i++);  
        if(read_input || scanf("%c",&char_read) > 0) // attempt to read 1 byte
        {
            // printf("\nValue of s is %d",s);
            printf("\nValue of read is %d",char_read);
            printf("\nChecked for %d or % d",'C','c');
            if(char_read == 'C' || char_read == 'c')
            {
                read_input = 1;
                break;
            }
        }
        printf("\nHere");
    }
    printf("\nI, %p survived while(1)\n",pthread_self());
    return NULL;
}

int main()
{
    // make stdin non-blocking
    fcntl(0, F_SETFL, fcntl(0, F_GETFL) | O_NONBLOCK);

pthread_t xthread,ythread,checkThread;  
char c1 = 'X', c2 = 'Z';
pthread_create(&xthread,NULL,print_fn,&c1);
pthread_create(&ythread,NULL,print_fn,&c2);
pthread_join(xthread,NULL);
pthread_join(ythread,NULL);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your inputs. Will try to do accordingly.

Comment: `volatile` would not help here: Please see a nice thread on this around this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6858294/694576